# Not enough space between equation and equation number

Tags: spacing, equations, equation-number

I compile a large equation in display mode with a label and this is what I get:
[image]

Is there any way to increase the spacing of the equation and the (45)?

Here is the code (sorry for including all packages, I am not sure which has an influence on my problem):

```
\documentclass[british,english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{esint}
\doublespacing
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{eqnarray}

\text{min}\left(1,\frac{\pi(x_{n+1})}{\pi(x_{n})}\prod_{i=0}^{L-1}\frac{P\Big((x_{n}^{i+1})^{*},(x_{n}^{i})^{*}\Big)}{P\Big(x_{n}^{i},x_{n}^{i+1}\Big)}\right) & = & \text{min}\left(1,e^{-   \beta\Delta\widetilde{H}}\right),\nonumber \\
 & = & \text{min}\left(1,e^{-\beta\sum_{i=0}^{L-1}\Delta\widetilde{H}_{i}}\right),\nonumber \\
 & = & \text{min}\left(1,e^{-\beta\left(\Delta U_{n}+\sum_{i=0}^{L-1}\Delta K_{BAB,i}\right)}\right),\label{eq:MH_effective_energy}

\end{eqnarray}

\end{document}
```

Comment: First of never use `eqnarray` as the image shows it uses way too much space around the `=` plus it happily overwrites the eqn number if it gets too close to it. Use `align` from `amsmath` instead.

Comment: Secondly never use `\text{min}`. The `\text` command does not do what you think it does. `\min` is already a build in math function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should *never* use `eqnarray`.

Better `equation` and `split`, in this case.

```
\documentclass[british]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{amsbsy}
%\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\usepackage[
  %unicode=true,
  pdfusetitle,
  bookmarks=true,
  bookmarksnumbered=false,
  bookmarksopen=false,
  breaklinks=false,
  pdfborder={0 0 1},
  backref=false,
  colorlinks=false,
]{hyperref}

\doublespacing

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:MH_effective_energy}
\begin{split}
\min\biggl(
  1,
  \frac{\pi(x_{n+1})}{\pi(x_{n})}
  \prod_{i=0}^{L-1}
    \frac{P\bigl((x_{n}^{i+1})^{*},(x_{n}^{i})^{*}\bigr)}
    {P\bigl(x_{n}^{i},x_{n}^{i+1}\bigr)}
\biggr)
&= \min(1,e^{-\beta\Delta\tilde{H}}), \\[-1ex]
&= \min\bigl(1,e^{-\beta\sum_{i=0}^{L-1}\Delta\tilde{H}_{i}}\bigr), \\
&= \min\bigl(1,e^{-\beta(\Delta U_{n}+\sum_{i=0}^{L-1}\Delta K_{BAB,i})}\bigr),
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I removed the overuse of `\left` and `\right`, changing also `\Big` into more suitable `\bigl` and `\bigr` pairs.

[image]

If you call `\usepackage[tbtags]{mathtools}`, you get

[image]

Instead of the manually guessed `\\[-1ex]` you might smash the bottom of the big left-hand side:

```
\documentclass[british]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[tbtags]{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
%\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\usepackage[
  %unicode=true,
  pdfusetitle,
  bookmarks=true,
  bookmarksnumbered=false,
  bookmarksopen=false,
  breaklinks=false,
  pdfborder={0 0 1},
  backref=false,
  colorlinks=false,
]{hyperref}

\doublespacing

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:MH_effective_energy}
\begin{split}
\smash[b]{\min\biggl(
  1,
  \frac{\pi(x_{n+1})}{\pi(x_{n})}
  \prod_{i=0}^{L-1}
    \frac{P\bigl((x_{n}^{i+1})^{*},(x_{n}^{i})^{*}\bigr)}
    {P\bigl(x_{n}^{i},x_{n}^{i+1}\bigr)}
\biggr)}
&= \min(1,e^{-\beta\Delta\tilde{H}}), \\
&= \min\bigl(1,e^{-\beta\sum_{i=0}^{L-1}\Delta\tilde{H}_{i}}\bigr), \\
&= \min\bigl(1,e^{-\beta(\Delta U_{n}+\sum_{i=0}^{L-1}\Delta K_{BAB,i})}\bigr),
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Points to note.

1. If you want UK English hyphenation rules you should not pass the `english` option (that's for US English).
2. `\text{min}` is wrong, use the predefined `\min` command.
3. There is no need for `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.
4. `hyperref` should be loaded last.
5. Why `latin9`? Ensure your documents are saved as UTF-8.
6. If you use `lualatex`, then don't load `fontenc`.
7. `amsbsy` and `amstext` are automatically loaded by `amsmath`, which in turn is loaded by `mathtools`.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the space after `\begin{eqnarray}` and before `\end{eqnarray}` may help.

```
\begin{eqnarray}
\text{min}\left(1,\frac{\pi(x_{n+1})}{\pi(x_{n})}\prod_{i=0}^{L-1}\frac{P\Big((x_{n}^{i+1})^{*},(x_{n}^{i})^{*}\Big)}{P\Big(x_{n}^{i},x_{n}^{i+1}\Big)}\right) & = & \text{min}\left(1,e^{-   \beta\Delta\widetilde{H}}\right),\nonumber \\
 & = & \text{min}\left(1,e^{-\beta\sum_{i=0}^{L-1}\Delta\widetilde{H}_{i}}\right),\nonumber \\
 & = & \text{min}\left(1,e^{-\beta\left(\Delta U_{n}+\sum_{i=0}^{L-1}\Delta K_{BAB,i}\right)}\right),\label{eq:MH_effective_energy}
\end{eqnarray}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you load `mathtools`, you'd better use its `multlined` environment:

```
    \documentclass[british,english]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[latin9]{luainputenc}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{babel}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{amsbsy}
    \usepackage{amstext}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{esint}
    \doublespacing
    \usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
     bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
     breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
     {hyperref}

    \makeatletter
    \usepackage[section]{placeins}
    \usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

    \makeatother

    \begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
    \begin{multlined}
    \min \left(1,\frac{\pi(x_{n+1})}{\pi(x_{n})}\prod_{i=0}^{L-1}\frac{P\Big((x_{n}^{i+1})^{*},(x_{n}^{i})^{*}\Big)}{P\Big(x_{n}^{i},x_{n}^{i+1}\Big)}\right) = \min \left(1,e^{- \beta\Delta\widetilde{H}}\right), \\
     = \min \left(1,e^{-\beta\sum_{i=0}^{L-1}\Delta\widetilde{H}_{i}}\right)
     = \min \left(1,e^{-\beta\left(\Delta U_{n}+\sum_{i=0}^{L-1}\Delta K_{BAB,i}\right)}\right),\label{eq:MH_effective_energy}
     \end{multlined}
    \end{equation}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since the `mathtools` package, it's not necessary to load `amsmath`.  Also, `hyperref should be loaded last.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I'lm sorry, I forgot to check this point when I used  the O.P.'s post code. I've fixed it now.